# Choice between Tilemill and Google Map Engine Lite

Tags: google-maps, tilemill

I have been using **Tilemill** for not very long, its such a good tool, but i have just recently found out about **Google Maps Engine Lite**, a map creation tool by google

I would love to know which tool is best for which scenarios.(Tilemill and Google Maps Engine Lite)

Answer (score 0):

The main benefit that Tilemill has over Google Maps Engine Lite is that it has the ability to create offline maps.

Also bare in mind that Google Maps Engine Lite is also in Beta...